# Setting Required Fields When Writing a Post

Tags: post-meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [don't publish custom post type post if a meta data field isn't valid](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15546/dont-publish-custom-post-type-post-if-a-meta-data-field-isnt-valid)

I originally asked this Q over at theme hybrid, Justin suggested I ask in here, he suggested javascript may be my best option, has anyone had any success in implementing the following?

if I were to have a community based site with multiple authors, is it possible to make all the fields inside the post area a required element before the post can be published?
for example, the author must add at least one tag, include the title, description and keywords in the meta, and choose the category.
Most of these requests would be fairly easy to explain, that the author needs to fill in these details but I am sure, and I know this from experience, many people will just not bother with filling in some of the necessary elements for publishing a post.
If I could set up a required field function that would force the user to fill in these details before the post will be published it would certainly save quite a few headaches.
Cheers.

Comment: [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15546/dont-publish-custom-post-type-post-if-a-meta-data-field-isnt-valid/15627#15627) can possibly point you in a direction.

Comment: for a community based site you should make a front end submission form rather than giving people the backend access.

Comment: Hi Sisir, not sure what you mean, sorry. I probably didn't explain myself properly, but what I want to do is create a site with multi authors, which would require them to have access to the wp-admin in order to publish their content.