# Only allow new subpages to be created

Tags: pages, admin, wp-admin, child-pages, children

I'm looking for a way to only allow users to create new subpages once there are nine pages that are parents/root pages. Once there are nine parent pages when trying to create a new parent the users will get an error message.

#### Edit:

Moved from the comments to @brasofilo s answer below:

> when I press submit it processes as it should but when the page refreshes I get the message: "Page updated" rather than "Page published. View page". So it's only saved as a draft, not actually published.

So the goal is to have the post status behave like it would for a default post type, when the new limit isn't triggering.

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code based in Bainternet's answer to this question: [Make Categories and Tags required in admin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/27446/12615)

See code comments.

```
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'wpse_59770_publish_admin_hook' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'wpse_59770_publish_admin_hook' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse_59770_pre_submit_validation', 'wpse_59770_ajax_pre_submit_validation' );

function wpse_59770_publish_admin_hook()
{
    global $current_screen;
    if( 'page' != $current_screen->post_type )
        return;

    ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#publish').click(function() 
            {
                var form_data = jQuery('#parent_id').val();
                form_data = ( '' != form_data ) ? '1' : '0';
                var data = {
                    action: 'wpse_59770_pre_submit_validation',
                    security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'pre_publish_validation' ); ?>',
                    form_data: form_data
                };
                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) 
                {
                    // OK, save page
                    if (response=='true') {
                        jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
                        jQuery('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                        jQuery('#post').submit();
                    }
                    // Not OK, display alert message
                    else
                    {
                        alert(response);
                        jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
                        jQuery('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}


function wpse_59770_ajax_pre_submit_validation()
{
    //simple Security check
    check_ajax_referer( 'pre_publish_validation', 'security' );

    // Parent is set, no further action
    if( '1' == $_POST['form_data'] )
    {
        echo 'true'; 
        die();
    }

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post_parent'=> 0, 'numberposts' => -1 );
    $parents_total = get_posts( $args );

    // Total parents is less than 9, no further action
    if( count($parents_total) < 9 )
    {
        echo 'true'; 
        die();
    }
    // No more parents allowed
    else
    {
        $error = "No more Parent Pages allowed";   
        echo $error; 
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: This script won't allow publishing of any page, sub page nor parent page. Ideas?

Comment: Not sure what gone wrong with this code, I always test before posting... With some debugging tool maybe you can make it work...

Comment: $args = array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post_parent'=> 0 ); should be $args = array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post_parent'=> 0, 'numberposts' => -1 ); That was the problem :)

Comment: Thanks @INT, code corrected. Next time, don't be shy and edit the Answer yourself ;)

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't know I could do that. However, still some problems after all, it seems however I do it, it will only save as draft not publish. I've tried on two different setups just to be sure. Ideas? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71009/firing-jquerypost-submit-creates-draft-rather-than-publishing-page

Comment: What exact problems are you facing? Is it the `Not OK` Ajax response?

Comment: No, it's nothing like that, when I press submit it processes as it should but when the page refreshes I get the message: "Page updated" rather than "Page published. View page". So it's only saved as a draft, not actually published. Did you try the above code without any troubles? I'm running 3.3.2, could that be an issue in that case?

Comment: On my side, it does what's asked: when creating or updating a page, it doesn't proceeds and displays a javascript alert if the total number of parent pages is 9 or great. **It shouldn't** update or publish anything... I'm on 3.4.2, but just tested with 3.2.1 and works as well.

Comment: Yes, that part is all fine, but what happens if there's less than 9 parent pages?

Comment: K, finally saw it... I guess that `jQuery('#post').submit();` is missing/messing something :/ Adding the action `wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse_59770_pre_submit_validation` (some target function) doesn't help either. But I cannot tackle the issue further now, will have to be in another moment... Try to search for similar Q&A or reduce the code to the minimum working block to try to locate the bug.

Comment: @INT Could you please **not** mark answers as solution if they don't work as such? Just update your question with the info that you want them to keep the original post status (or get "published" as status). This is very annoying for other people reading this later and then stumbling upon a not-solved problem in the comments.