# Wordpress custom post action hook

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, actions

I'm working on a plugin for wordpress that I would like to fire every time a custom post of the type 'job' is posted, published, edited, trashed, untrashed, etc. (basically whenever there is an update to that post type).

I'm having a bit of trouble finding the correct action hook to call. I have searched, and from my understanding I can't use for example (publish_post) because I am using a custom post type, so it should be something along the lines of (publish_job) or publish_post_job. However, those don't seem to work for me either, if I go in to the jobs category and publish a draft in the jobs category.

So, I guess I have two questions:

1) What is the correct action I should be using in the context of a custom post type.

2) a. Is there some sort of action that I can use to encompass all sorts of changes to the jobs category (ie: post editing, publishing, unpublishing, trash/untrash, etc). b. If not, how would I go about calling add_action for all of those possible actions.

Thank you!

Comment: `transition_post_status` does all in one

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pieter said, you can use `transition_post_status`:

```
function wpse_187997_job_status( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type === 'job' && $new_status !== $old_status ) {
         // Post type "job" and status has changed
    }
}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_187997_job_status', 10, 3 );
```